# Error After VTune Installation: Unable To Open X Display

Tags: linux, intel, intel-oneapi, intel-vtune

From the download page, I have installed oneAPI Base Toolkit. I got the following Error Post    Installation.

```
 Error: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 86: unknown element "blank"
    [104618:0622/123508.008581:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1409)] Unable to open X display.
```

The installation is done by current user (nonroot user).How to fix this error?

Comment: Does `xterm` or `xdpyinfo` work if you run them from the same command line?  If not, make sure your `DISPLAY` env var is set correctly, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running the below command to check if the required packages for loading the GUI of Intel oneAPI Toolkits are installed correctly:

```
sudo apt-get install x11-apps libgbm1 libatspi2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 xdg-utils libnotify4
```

Additionally, try setting the DISPLAY environment variables using **any** of the below command:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export DISPLAY="`grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | sed 's/nameserver //'`:0"
```

Note: If you are running the toolkits inside a VM/WSL where the host OS is Windows, you need to install a display handler inside Windows to get the GUI. For example: VxSsrv, Xming